# Simple Differentiation problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Can we write in this way
$$(\vec{ r}\times \vec{\dot x}) =\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(\vec{\dot{ r}}\times \vec{x})$$
Dot represents here the time derivative whereas $\mathbf r$ is the position vector.

**EDIT**

> To exclude rotation of the molecule, the total angular momentum must vanish: $$D=\sum_\alpha m_\alpha[\mathbf r_\alpha\times\mathbf v_\alpha]\simeq\sum_\alpha m_\alpha[\mathbf r_{\alpha0}\times \dot{\mathbf x}_\alpha]=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\sum_\alpha m_\alpha[\dot{\mathbf{r}_{\alpha0}\times\mathbf{x}_\alpha}],$$

Comment: I think here is true: $\frac{d}{dt}(\vec{\dot r}\times \vec{x})= \vec{\ddot r}\times \vec{x} + \vec{\dot r}\times \vec{\dot x}$ because of linearity of "$\times$".

Comment: I have got it also, but I'm confused about what I wrote. This is related with angular momentum and I have writen without m.

Comment: @ user2378:  I think that, to make real progress with this problem, you need to define the relationship between $\vec r$ and $\vec x$; you formula is certainly not true *sans* some such definition.  Hoseyn Heydari's comment is correct in the general case.

Comment: @user2378 Perhaps if you ask this in physics.estackexchange.com you give more useful answers.

Comment: @user2378 Giving the meaning of $x$ and $r$ or say the reference of equation may help too.

Comment: There is a typo in the book: $$\frac d{dt} \sum m_{\alpha}[\mathbf r_{\alpha 0}\times \mathbf x_{\alpha}]$$ instead. Moreover $\mathbf r_{\alpha 0}$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Since cross-product is bilinear, the correct formula is 
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\vec{\dot r}\times \vec{x})= \vec{\ddot r}\times \vec{x} + \vec{\dot r}\times \vec{\dot x}$$
(given by [Hoseyn Heydari](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562867/simple-differentiation-problem#comment1193775_562867)).

[Tony Piccolo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562867/simple-differentiation-problem#comment1199358_562867) noticed that the formula from which the question originated had a typo. The correct form is 
$$D=\sum_\alpha m_\alpha[\mathbf r_\alpha\times\mathbf v_\alpha]\simeq\sum_\alpha m_\alpha[\mathbf r_{\alpha0}\times \dot{\mathbf x}_\alpha]=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\sum_\alpha m_\alpha[ {\mathbf{r}_{\alpha0}\times\mathbf{x}_\alpha}]$$ 
where the last equality holds because $\mathbf{r}_{\alpha0}$ is constant.